# creating large promoted links in size 500*500 px

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding

hi how can we create promoted links in size of 500*500 px As I know the default size is 150* 150 and I want it to become more larger

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS

```
            div.ms-promlink-body {
                height: 500px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-root {
                height: 510px !important;
                width: 510px !important;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > span {
                height: 500px !important;
                width: 500px !important;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img {
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium {
                height: 500px;
                padding: 0;
            }

            li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
                font-size: 11px;
                line-height: 16px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeCollapsed, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeExpanded {
                padding: 3px;
            }

            div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed {
                background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #002E4F;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 16px;
                min-height: 36px;
                min-width: 97px;
                padding-left: 3px;
                position: absolute;
                top: -36px;
            }

            li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium {
                font-size: 11px;
                line-height: 14px;
                padding: 3px;
            }
            .ms-tileview-tile-content img {
                width:500px!important;
                height:500px!important;
            }
```